# Кеширование ORM Kohana3

Tags: кэширование, orm, kohana

Как можно закешировать результат работы ORM в Kohana 3.2 без особых костылей? Хоть и знаю способы, но они на столько корявы, что самому противно)

Answer (score 1):

```
class ORM extends Kohana_ORM
{
/**
* @return array
*/
public function list_columns()
{
$_columns_data = Cache::instance()->get($this->_table_name ."structure");

if( $_columns_data === NULL )
{
$_columns_data = $this->_db->list_columns($this->_table_name);
Cache::instance()->set($this->_table_name ."structure", $_columns_data, Date::DAY);
}

return $_columns_data;
}
}
```

Comment: Так это понятно, но у меня цель кешировать сам результат запроса

Comment: `->find_all()` в ORM кешируется по умолчанию